# ¿Como llenar un Picker con información de una tabla?

Tags: react-native

Buenas tardes, soy nuevo en el mundo de `react-native`, mi pregunta es como lleno un `picker` con la información de una table.

He intentado el código siguiente, aunque trae los datos no logro que pinte los `Picker.Item`, espero puedan ayudarme:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Picker,
  Button,
  Modal,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      torneo: '',
      torneos: null,
    };

  }

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchTorneos();       
  }

  fetchTorneos() {
    var baseURL = 'http://dominoplus.codigoprofesional.com/data/get_torneos.php';
    fetch(baseURL, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          if(responseData.message){
            this.setState({isLoading: !this.state.isLoading});
            alert(responseData.message);
          }else{
            this.setState({isLoading: !this.state.isLoading, torneos:responseData});
            // Comprobacion de que recibe los datos
            this.state.torneos.forEach(function(data) {
              alert(data.nombre);
            });
          }
        })
        .done();
  } 

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 10}}>
      <Text style={styles.header1}>Selecciona un Torneo</Text>

      <Picker style={styles.picker}
        itemStyle={styles.items}
        selectedValue={this.state.torneo}
        onValueChange={(tor) => this.setState({torneo: tor})}
      >
            // Esta sección no me reconoce los datos, me dice "null is not an object ('evaluating this.state.torneos.map') cuando trato de correr la app en el simulador. 

        {
          this.state.torneos.map((data, i) => {
            return <Picker.Item value={data.id} label={data.nombre} key={i} /> 
          })
        }


    </Picker>

      <View style={styles.separador}></View>
      <Text style={styles.header2}>Crea un torneo</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textinput}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
          value={this.state.text}
          placeholder="Nombre del torneo"
          placeholderTextColor="#ddd"
        />

        <TouchableHighlight 
          onPress={() => {
            alert("¡El torneo ha sido creado!")
          }} 
          style={styles.submitButton}
        >
          <Text style={styles.submitText}>CREAR</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>

      );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  separador: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderTopWidth: 1
  },
  textinput: {
    height: 40, 
    borderColor: '#eee', 
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10
  },
  view: {
    flex: 0.25,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    padding: 20
  },
  img: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  header1: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#444'
  },
  header2: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#444'
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'red',
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10
  },
  submitButton: {
     backgroundColor: '#2196F3',
     padding: 10,
     marginTop: 10,
     marginLeft: 10,
     marginRight: 10
  },
  submitText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#fff'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que intentas crear algo dentro de un componente que ya existe.

En tiempo de ejecución, los elementos dentro del picker no van a existir cuando el picker se crea por lo tanto lo que debes hacer es crear los Picker.Item en el render y después en el return agregarlos. Te dejo un ejemplo.

```
render(){
    let itemsInPicker = items.map( data=> {
                    return <Picker.Item label={data.name} key={data.id} value={data.id}/>
                    })

     return(
             <Picker
               ...
               >
               { itemsInPicker }
             </Picker>)
}
```